# Stripe Payments and Codeigniter | Getting return values

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

Okay, So within my codeigniter application, I am using the [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). I am using the custom option with the following code:

```
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_qzoaU1JTxL7DHF0i4aq3o3Q8',
    image: 'https://candykingdom.org/assets/img/logo/ck_castle.png',
    token: function(token, args) {
      var token = token.id;
      var cost = $('#prices').html();
      var total = cost.replace('.', '');
      var price = total.replace('$', '');
      var price = $.trim(price);
      dataString = 'token=' + token + '&amount=' + price;
      //alert(dataString); return false;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/checkout/doCharge",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var price = $('#prices').html();
      var total = price.replace('.', '');
      var price = total.replace('$', '');
      // Open Checkout with further options
      handler.open({
        name: 'Candy Kingdom',
        description: 'On-line Purchase',
        amount: price,
        allowRememberMe: false,

      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

That creates the checkout and takes care of all that.

---

Then I have the codeigniter Stripe library installed and in the `/checkout/doCharge/` I have the following code:

```
public function doCharge()
{
    $this->load->library('stripe');

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $card = $_POST['token'];

    $desc = 'Candy Kingdom On-line Order';

    $response = $this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);

    echo $response;
}
```

What I am wanting to know is, In the function above, How do I manage to tell whether or not the card was approved/denied. And if it was denied how do I get the failure message from stripe?

I know that stripe [returns this when you charge a card](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object), I'm just not sure what variable explains the approve/deny and the failing message and how to properly pull them from the `json return from stripe.`

When I run a test card I receive the following in the echo $response;

[image]

Comment: I get an error `Trying to get non-object`

Comment: What does `$response` look like ? Is it just a JSON string or an already decoded JSON object ?

Comment: It is just a json I'm quite sure.

Comment: Yes but is it already decoded or is just a string (and in which case you'll need to run `json_decode()` on it) ?

Comment: I do not have much experience in json. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors), you just check the HTTP response code. "In general, codes in the 2xx range indicate success, codes in the 4xx range indicate an error that resulted from the provided information (e.g. a required parameter was missing, a charge failed, etc.), and codes in the 5xx range indicate an error with Stripe's servers."

The bigger issue I see with your code is that you are trusting the client to send you the correct total. If I go an edit the total variable on the client before submitting the charge, then you will charge whatever I edited the variable to show. You should store and/or calculate the total amount on the server and not trust the client to send you the correct total.

Comment: The total is displayed in a `<span></span>` and the amount is pulled from there. I don't see where the user would be able to edit the total. Other than editing the code in the chrome inspector.

Comment: I updated my code to use the session variable in the actual charge script.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
public function doCharge() {
    $this->load->library('stripe');

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $card = $_POST['token'];

    $desc = 'Candy Kingdom On-line Order';

    if ((int)$amount < $_SESSION["amount"]) {
        echo "Incorrect amount";
    } else {
        $response = json_decode($this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc));

        if ($response->paid) {
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            echo "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

First we make sure that the amount is the same or greater than what we want, then we do the payment and decode Stripe's JSON response and check if it succeeded.